# Summing NAs across selected column names in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to build a loop in R, where R sums the number of NAs across a row for selected columns. The columns that I am interested in summing all start with "item" and a number follows (e.g. item1, item2, item3, etc). The code that I had built does not seem to work... Any advice would be appreciated!

```
df$var<- NA

cols.want<- paste ("item", 1:169, sep = "")

for (i in cols.want{
  df$var<-rowSums(is.na(df[i]))
}
```

Comment: You need `rowSums(is.na(df[cols.want]))`  No need to loop.

Comment: If you're feeling lazy with `dplyr` .... `data%>%
select(starts_with("item"))%>%
is.na()%>%
rowSums()`

Comment: a regular expression using `grep()` related function to check for column matches would be normal.